# Adaptar IDBSet EF6 para EF Core

Tags: entity-framework

Estou migrando de EntityFramework 6x para o EntityFramework core, mas estou apanhando um pouco para implementar uma interface IDBSet que não existe no EF Core. No Lugar dela, preciso utilizar algo como MeuContexto.Set... mas não sei como fazer isso corretamente. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

//Meu Repositório Base

```js
 public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        protected readonly SistemaComercialContext Context;

        public RepositoryBase(SistemaComercialContext dbContext)
        {
            Context = dbContext;
        }
        public void Add(TEntity obj)
        {
           Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
        }

        public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllReadOnly()
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
        }
        public void Update(TEntity obj)
        {
            var entry = Context.Entry(obj);
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(obj);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity obj)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(obj);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Context.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

//Minha Interface Curso

```js
public interface ICursoRepository : IRepositoryBase<Curso>
    {
        Curso ObterPorNome(string nome);
        Curso ObterPorIdComDependencias(Guid cursoId);
        IEnumerable<Curso> ObterGrid();
    }
```

//E por último, Meu Repositório no qual preciso usar o contexto

```js
public class CursoRepository : RepositoryBase<Curso>, ICursoRepository
    {
        public CursoRepository(SistemaComercialContext dbContext)
            : base(dbContext)
        {

        }
        public IEnumerable<Curso> ObterGrid()
        {
                return DbSet
                    .Include("TipoCurso")
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList();
        }

        public Curso ObterPorIdComDependencias(Guid cursoId)
        {
            return DbSet
                 .Include("TipoCurso")
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CursoId == cursoId);
        }

        public Curso ObterPorNome(string descricao)
        {
            return Find(x => x.Nome == descricao).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: No lugar de `DBSet` é `dbContext.Curso.Include` ....

Comment: Ele não aceitou usar "dbContext". Eu declarei uma property acima do Construtor "protected readonly SistemaComercialContext Context;" e Setei dentro do mesmo " Context = dbContext;", mas não sei se seria o correto...

Comment: SistemaComercialContext  é o Entity Framework?:

Comment: Sim! É a minha classe de Contexto do EntityFRamework Core.

Comment: É Context.Curso ... Faz o teste